# Jquery - fancybox and callback

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have problem with fancybox.
I want to write a function that will run when the fancybox opened. How and when to call the function?

Example:

```
function myFunc() {
    alert("Opened!");
}

$('.content a').fancybox({ 
    'hideOnContentClick': false ,
    'callBackOnShow': myFunc(), // This not working! It call function when page is loaded
    'frameWidth': 920,
    'frameHeight': 530
});
```

Comment: If people come here and are seeking the callback for the new version of Fancybox : check for the "onComplete" attribute.

Comment: For fancybox version 2 or greater it was changed to afterLoad. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of `myFunc()` use `myFunc`. In javascript, a function with parens (and/or args) means you want to call it. A function name without them means you just want a reference to that function (which is probably what fancybox wants from you)

Answer (score 11):

This works

```
$("#element").fancybox({
    onStart     :   function() {
        return window.confirm('Continue?');
    },
    onCancel    :   function() {
        alert('Canceled!');
    },
    onComplete  :   function() {
        alert('Completed!');
    },
    onCleanup   :   function() {
        return window.confirm('Close?');
    },
    onClosed    :   function() {
        alert('Closed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I wonder, why the original callbacks did not work: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Answer (score 10):

The newest way how to make it work is using afterShow or beforeShow:

```
$("a#registrace").fancybox({
  beforeShow   : function() {
    alert('its working!');
    validate_reg_form();
  }
});
```

I am loading registration form through ajax and I need to enable form-validation. In both cases (before and after), the content is already loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, on checking the docs, you have a typo in your option list...

You have `callBackOnShow` but it should be `callbackOnShow` (lower case b)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:-

```
function myFunc() {
    alert("Opened!");
}

$('.content a').fancybox({ 
    'hideOnContentClick': false ,
    'callBackOnShow': myFunc, // no brackets
    'frameWidth': 920,
    'frameHeight': 530
});
```

Or, you can make an anonymous function...

```
$('.content a').fancybox({ 
    'hideOnContentClick': false ,
    'callBackOnShow': function() { alert('hello'); },
    'frameWidth': 920,
    'frameHeight': 530
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'callbackOnShow': myFunc
```

lower case b as the options are case sensitive,
and no brackets on myFunc, as you want to pass the function as an option, not call it.

Answer (score 0):

As your title says "Jquery - fancybox and callback", You can a complete list of callback options for the fancybox 2 plugin found under the tab callbacks.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

If your using the old fancybox, maybe upgrading to fancybox2 as the new plugin has better features, with more control.