# How to hide photos until menu is expanded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a photo gallery with different drop down menus containing separate categories. Everything works great, except that when I test the gallery page all the images are visible while they load, and then once they're fully loaded they disappear into their said categories (as it should be to begin with). My question is this...

Is there a way to hide all the photos until someone clicks and expands a menu option? Or perhaps a better way to go at this all together?

Here is a link to the gallery site... http://wayhigh.we.bs/Fireball%20Site/gallery.html
Here is a sample of the html...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="st-accordion" class="st-accordion">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Functional<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span>        </a>
                <div class="st-content">
                    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="functional" href="images/wyzeguy.jpg" title="Wyze guy rigs">
                        <img src="images/smallwyzeguy.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="functional" href="images/dragon.jpg" title="Dragon">
                        <img src="images/smalldragon.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
```

there are several of these menu items...

script for the accordion menu...

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#st-accordion').accordion(
    {
        oneOpenedItem   : true
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox(
    {
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : 
        {
            title   : 
            {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : 
            {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a better solution than what I've come up with? Or a way to stream-line my solution?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I think a simple way of hiding the photos till load would be to make them `display:none` until the document is ready. Create a class in the css called `hidden` and give it the styling of `display:none`.  Add the class to all the images.

Then in the `$(document).ready` call add a line as the fancybox callback or after you setup the fancy box that looks like, `$("img.hidden").removeClass("hidden");`.

Comment: The problem here is that the JS is taking a very long time to load, and therefore you see the images in between. The CSS you mention should be enough. After loading, Fancybox does hide the images, and shows them again when clicked, but by then it's too late.

Comment: Ok well then in that case do not add the js I mentioned. Just add the CSS. That way the images are hidden till the FancyBox framework can take over.

Comment: I thought this was going to be the solution, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Still get the same effect. Removing the js only hides the photos completely; even when the menu is expanded

Comment: What happens if you leave the js in?

Comment: It seemed to act the same way as before I added the **hidden** class. Loads slowly and hides the images after they've been visible for a while

Comment: The js should make sure the document and the FancyBox framework is ready before making the images viewable when the menu is expanded.

Comment: That's because js is asynchronous by nature which is why the js should go in a callback function in the FancyBox framework/library. That way it will only be called once everything is setup.

Comment: As stated in the comments on this post,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910455/jquery-fancybox-and-callback set the onComplete attribute to the reference of a function that calls the js I mentioned. That should solve your problem.