# Call Function on fancy box's div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I want to call a function on clicking the div of title attribute of fancybox popup.

my code is as below :

```
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'cyclic'    : 'true',
    'padding'   : '0px',
    'nextEffect'    :   'fade',
    'prevEffect'    :   'fade',
    'titleShow'    :   'false',
    'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        return '<span id="fancybox_popup"><span class="popup_title"> ' + title + '</span><span class="popup_options"><a class="fancy_detail_opt" href="#" ><div class="icon icon-plus-1"></div></a></span></span>';
    }
});
```

I want to hide-show (toogle) "popup_title" div on click of "fancy_detail_opt" div.

Any suggestion for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - fancybox and callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910455/jquery-fancybox-and-callback)

Comment: what issue you have faced??

Comment: In the documentation on http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ there are 3 tabs. Go to the third one that says callbacks and find the suitable one for you.

Comment: what version of fancybox?